# Azure Resource Groups - Moving to a new Resource Group. Is there any downtime?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-group, azure-regions

I have a bunch of resources located in East US, however the Resource Group was created using West US location. Although the Resource Groups are just a way to logically group resources, I would like to match the location of the Resource Group with the actual resources.

If I create a new Resource Group on the East US location and then move all the resources from the old Resource Group to the new one, is there going to be any downtime during this operation or will the resources continue operating as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that the resources would be shut down during your [migration between regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-tutorial-migrate). But they will work as perfect as before when you finish the migration.

If you do not change the regions of the resources. There can be no downtime during the migration. Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources).

Comment: Ouch! That's a bummer. Is there any documentation that provides such information? Also, what if the region where the resource group was created is down? Will the resources in it keep working if they belong to a different region? Thanks!

Comment: If you create the resources in Availability Set, it can be work as normal when the region is down. Take a look at [Availability Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/manage-availability?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Fclassic%2Ftoc.json).

Comment: I'm glad it can help you.

Comment: You did, indeed!